# Iterating through dataframe using regular expression python

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I a trying parse SI type patterns in another column in a DF or in a list
I tried 2 things:

```
|    a             |
-------------------+
| Builder          |
| left             |
| SI_NAME lide_on  |
| SI_ID 456        |
| Scheduling Info  |

df['b']= df['a'].apply(lambda row: re.findall('\SI_\w+\s',row))
```

and

```
list_DF=[]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    list_DF.append(re.findall('\SI_\w+\s',row[0]))
```

I am not able to get the result and the first one returned an empty list in the new column

Comment: Note `\S` matches a non-whitespace, not `S`.

Comment: This regular expression works well on one sentence, fails while iterating over the rows in the dataframe

Comment: Try `df['b'] = df['a'].str.findall(r'^SI_\w+'').apply(','.join)` (`.apply(','.join)` is redundant, but will return just strings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use something like

```
df['b'] = df['a'].str.findall(r'^SI_\w+')
```

Using `.str` will force the contents to be parsed as string.

The `^SI_\w+` pattern matches `SI_` and then 1+ word chars only at the beginning of the string (due to `^`) - it looks like the entries you are after follow this pattern. You may add `.apply(','.join)` or something like that at the end to get string data in the resulting column.